# How to install golang-libguestfs package?

Tags: go, virtual-machine

I am trying to install the libguestfs package for golang but couldn't find the way to do so. I went through [this](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/gabrielhartmann/libguestfs/golang?tab=overview) but it didn't work for me and I believe it's empty. I see only test files [here](https://github.com/libguestfs/libguestfs/tree/master/golang)

Following is the content of the README

```
$GOPATH
-------

http://golang.org/doc/code.html

Note that $GOPATH is set (by the ./run script) to the
libguestfs/golang directory so that "installs" happen in the local
build tree.
```

From this I could figure out that I need to build the package but again for that, I couldn't find some help or proper document.

Is there any way to do the installation? I am using RHEL 7.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Libguestfs (the C library) is packaged already in RHEL 7, so I would suggest first of all installing that using `yum install libguestfs`.  That's the version that Red Hat supports.

We don't ship the golang bindings, not even in RHEL 8.  Furthermore the bindings in all languages are generated from a mechanical description of the API and thus not stored directly inside our git repository.  That's why you could only find test files in git.

However we do distribute the generated files in the tarballs, so an easy way is to grab the latest tarball from https://download.libguestfs.org/1.42-stable/ and look in the `golang/src/libguestfs.org/guestfs` subdirectory of the tarball.

The harder way is to generate them from git.  These steps worked for me on RHEL 7.7, YMMV:

```
sudo yum-builddep libguestfs
git clone https://github.com/libguestfs/libguestfs
cd libguestfs
git submodule init
git submodule update
./bootstrap
./autogen.sh SUPERMIN=/usr/bin/supermin5
make
```

and again look in the `golang/` subdirectory.

I'm reasonably sure that golang bindings from one version should work with another version of the C library.  We did test this at one point in time, so if it's no longer true then it may have regressed as these things sometimes do.